# Appending new tag in xml DOM method sometimes add junk tag and file is useless in android

Tags: android, xml, dom

In android app, I am storing the data into xml file. I am using DOM method to add new tags in xml file. Sometimes it adds some junk tag and file is no more use. what is reason for this behaviour? I read that DOM is slow for large size file. The maximum file size is around 800KB. Is that reason for this issue?
Could you provide the solution to avoid this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainCategory>
  <Type>Nos</Type>
  <Category>Briyani</Category>
  <CurrentStock>0.00</CurrentStock>
  <Purchased>
     <Items>
     <Date>01/12/2016</Date>
     <Quantity>116.00</Quantity>
     <ManualUpdate>Yes</ManualUpdate>
     <SourceDetails>NIL</SourceDetails>
     <Reason>None</Reason>
     </Items>
   </Purchased>
</MainCategory>
```

The files format looks like above. The purchased items added repeatedly.
But Sometimes part of string from end tag(***nCategory>***) added as junk and file is useless like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainCategory>
  <Type>Nos</Type>
  <Category>Briyani</Category>
  <CurrentStock>0.00</CurrentStock>
  <Purchased>
     <Items>
     <Date>01/12/2016</Date>
     <Quantity>116.00</Quantity>
     <ManualUpdate>Yes</ManualUpdate>
     <SourceDetails>NIL</SourceDetails>
     <Reason>None</Reason>
     </Items>
   </Purchased>
</MainCategory>nCategory>
```

**Adding new tag code as below:**

```
try{
        String filepath = ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+XmlfileName;
        File inputFile = new File(filepath);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputFile);

        // Get the root element
        Node InvItems = doc.getFirstChild();
        NodeList list = InvItems.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = list.item(i);
            //Update Current Stock
            if ("CurrentStock".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                node.setTextContent(CurrentStock);
            }
            if (PurOrUsedStr.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                    // append a new node to staff
                    Element p1 = doc.createElement("Items");

                    Element date = doc.createElement("Date");
                    date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(DateStr));
                    p1.appendChild(date);

                    Element quantity = doc.createElement("Quantity");
                    quantity.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(UpdateQuantity));
                    p1.appendChild(quantity);

                    Element AutoOrManual = doc.createElement("ManualUpdate");
                    AutoOrManual.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(AutoManuUpdate));
                    p1.appendChild(AutoOrManual);

                    Element SrcDetails = doc.createElement("SourceDetails");
                    SrcDetails.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(SourceDetails));
                    p1.appendChild(SrcDetails);

                    Element ReasonSplCmt = doc.createElement("Reason");
                    ReasonSplCmt.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ReasonStr));
                    p1.appendChild(ReasonSplCmt);

                    Element UpdateTime = doc.createElement("UpdateTime");
                    UpdateTime.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(UpdateTimeStr));
                    p1.appendChild(UpdateTime);

                    node.appendChild(p1);

                    IsPurOrUsedTagAvail = true;
                }

        }
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
        StatusStr = "Exception";
    }catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        StatusStr = "Exception";
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        StatusStr = "Exception";
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        StatusStr = "Exception";
        sae.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you try writing to another file (i.e. not the same file as the input file)? Or insert `inputFile.delete()` before writing the file.

Comment: My filename should be same also it should be contains all the information present already in the file. I just append the new tag with root tag. Does 'inputFile.delete()' statement delete all the content in file?

Comment: This issue happened rarely. I have set of around 200 files. The files are updated daily. The error is not happening on all the days in all files but rarely on some days in some of the files.